# Firefox and window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, hash

Im currently testing an AJAX app in firefox 3.6.15 that uses window.location.hash changes for navigation when I need the page to not reload.

I have a link that does this:

```
var editCategoryClick = (function (categoryID) {
                return function () {
                    if (window.location.hash != window.location.hash + '/' + categoryID) {
                        window.location.hash = window.location.hash + '/' + categoryID;
                    }
                }
            })(category.ID);
```

This works great.  I end up with this result.
'#numbers/categories'   becomes '#numbers/categories/eba38179-d492-4bb9-ba66-1bfa4c3571fb'

However, if I manually go into the browser navigation bar and change '#numbers/categories' to #numbers/categoriesX',    the hash will not update when I run the click function.

I do not have this problem in any of the other browsers I am testing  chrome, safari, ie9, ie8.  Only firefox exhibits this behavior.  I know its a rare case, but its still a UX issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `window.location.hash != window.location.hash + '/' + categoryID` always returns `true` I guess - it's like checking for non-equality of some `x` to `x + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Attach an `onhashchange` event listener to probe for hash change. For unsupported browser, use `setInterval` to detect the change.
2. Why reinvent the wheel if you could use something like [jQuery History](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/)?

Comment: Do you know if there's something equivalent in Dojo?